# Issues with running test cases inside buildSrc directory

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

I have a custom Java class that performs Caesar Cipher encryption and I want to unit-test it. But the problem is when I try to test it the IDE shows an error:

> java.lang.Throwable: Unable to determine gradle tasks to execute
>       at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:126)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.DefaultGradleBuilder.build(DefaultGradleBuilder.java:42)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.doExecuteTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:360)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:268)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:122)
>       at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.lambda$compileAndRun$0(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:298)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here is my `build.gradle` file contents for `buildSrc` directory:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src/main/groovy'
        }
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation localGroovy()
    implementation gradleApi()
    implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:$codec_version"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit_version"
}
```

P.S.: when I try to run the test class from the command line using -`Dtest.single=package.*` - it does not find the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a WONTFIX bug reported here https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1553

As a workaround (posted in issue) you can use `--tests` ie:

```
# Executes all tests in SomeTestClass
gradle test --tests SomeTestClass

# Executes a single specified test in SomeTestClass
gradle test --tests SomeTestClass.someSpecificMethod

gradle test --tests SomeTestClass.*someMethod*
```

Documented here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#simple_name_pattern